# Have bash script run against a live file - Is it possible?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, tail

I have a script I've written and (finally) have it working like I want it to, as long as I run it against a static file. Is there a way to tail a live file and have the script perform its actions against the tail file as each line comes into the live file?

I tried

```
tail -f logfile.txt | ./myscript.sh
```

and

```
./myscript.sh <logfile.txt
```

But neither of them seem to produce the desired results. My guess is that (in the first example) that myscript.sh won't run until tail -f finishes, which defeats the purpose :)

I don't know why the second example doesn't work...seems like it should, but it reads in all the contents of the file, but not the new lines as they come into logfile.txt

Comment: There are workarounds. It sounds like an X-Y question..Whats the content of `myscript.sh` ? what is your final goal with the `logfile.txt` ?

Comment: Could work with named pipe

Comment: The script I wrote parses through the firewall logs, identifies script kiddies, port scanners, brute force attacks, etc. I have it remove any UDP or ICMP entries. It them does a whois lookup on the IP, gets the abuse contact for that subnet, and sends them an email along with the details of the intrusion attempt. It also records the IP address that it just reported to a logfile resulting in a list to be checked against to ensure the abuse admin gets only a single report on that particular IP. Most of the time the IP will scan the entire /24 resulting in 250 entries.

Comment: (continued) If I sent 250 emails all at once to the same abuse admin they'd likely be ignored and my mailserver would start showing up on blacklists. (If I post my code I'd worry I'd hurt you from the laughter it would cause...The entire 45 lines or so f code could likely have been done with five or less if one of you were doing it.) But it works, but only on yesterday's (static) file. I'd really like for it to be able to process the firewall log line-by-line as the intrusions are attempted.

Comment: In the first example, you probably meant to use a pipe `|` rather than an output redirection `>` (which will overwrite the contents of your script file, rather than providing standard input to it). Beyond that, you *may* have issues with buffering.

Comment: You're right steeldriver - I did mean to have a pipe there. I must've had greater-than on the brain and didn't catch it when I typed my question. I was also trying to find a way to make tail -f start from the beginning of the file (since it was created at midnight), rather than starting with the last few lines, but haven't explored that yet in-depth. If I can't get it to process the text as it arrives, going back to the beginning won't help :)

Comment: @samgoober `tail -f -n +1 logfile.txt | ./myscript.sh`? And please [edit] your question instead of writing long comments.

Comment: +1 or possibly `-F` if logfile.txt is a file that may be rotated out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple proof-of-concept:

In myscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  echo "syslog says: $line"
done
```

Then in a terminal:

```
$ tail -n 0 -F /var/log/syslog | ./myscript.sh
```

(note that I'm using `-n 0` because I don't want to process **any** previous log content; if you want to process it **all** then change that to `-n +1` to start the tail from the first line). I'm also using `-F` instead of `-f` so that tail will retry if the original file becomes inaccessible - for example as a result of being rotated out.

In a different terminal

```
$ logger "logger says hello"
```

You should immediately see in the first terminal something like

```
syslog says: Dec 11 13:48:54 T61p steeldriver: logger says hello
```

If it doesn't work, perhaps it's because whatever is writing to the logfile is doing so in a buffered manner, or you're processing it in a buffered manner within your script (`grep` is sometimes the culprit: it has a `--line-buffered` option that may be useful in that case).

Comment: I just about have it steeldriver. I'm running into issues (I think so anyway) on account of two nested while read loops inside the script. But you've got me heading in the right direction. Thank you for your help.

muru - My apologies if I broke the rules. I was asked "Whats the content of myscript.sh ? what is your final goal with the logfile.txt", and was making an effort to answer those two questions. I'm really sorry if I upset you. Didn't mean to.